# Static variable cannot be accessed from another class

Tags: objective-c, variables, static

I have a static variable that i want to access from another class in the same project in X-Code. I have declared it in the .h file AND the .m file, gave it a value, and then when i accessed the other class, i got an error message saying that:

"Property 'xx' is not found on object of type 'yy'"

i declared the variable as extern in the .h, and redeclared it as the variable type in the .m. I have tried to change it to static in the .h, but it still doesn't work. And yes, i have imported the file containing the variable, in case that is the problem.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT:

this is the code that i'm currently using:

*source.h*

```
static int anObject;

@interface source : NSObject
```

*source.m*

```
static int a = 2

@implementation source
```

*destination.m*

```
# include "source.h"

@implementation destination

- (void) anObjectTestFunction 

{     
  printf("%d", source.anObject); //the first version
  printf("%d", anObject); //second version  
}
```

now after i went to the second version, the variable anObject in destination.h can be accessed, but its value is not 2, it's 0. I want it to follow the one i declared in source.h.

Comment: sounds like you're trying to access a global variable as if it were a property on an object.  just type out the variable name alone. but, paste some code in and it would be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: What makes you think that `anObject` should be set to 2? You haven't set it to anything. In your .m file you set `a = 2` which I would expect to be 2. `anObject` is never set from what I can see from your example and since it is an int it will be 0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am assuming the static variable declared in the .h file is outside the `@interface`. So something like:

```
static NSString *myObjectTest = @"Test";

@interface MyObject : NSObject 
@end
```

If that is the case then you will not be able to access it using something like:

```
MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
[obj myObject]
```

or

```
obj.myObject
```

That is what is giving you the "Property 'xx' is not found on object of type 'yy'". That static variable is not a property on the object of MyObject.

That static variable is accessible like so `myObjectTest` as long as you import the .h file

**Update**
See Chuck's comment below why this is a bad idea to do this way.

Comment: Putting a static variable in your header is almost never what you want to do. It will give every file that uses your class a different copy of the variable.

Comment: I agree. I'm just assuming (from what was said) that that is what is being done.

Answer (score 4):

You seem confused about what a static variable is. In other languages like Java or C++, "static" can mean one of two things. In a file or function scope, it means a variable scoped to either that file or function that exists for your program's entire lifetime. In a class scope, it means just a class variable.

C++ has both definitions, Java only has the second definition, but Objective-C only has the first definition: A static variable can only be used in the place where it's declared. There is no such thing as an "extern static" variable because the two are contradictory. You probably want either a global variable or a static variable with a class method to access it.

Answer (score -1):

Could this be a namespace issue? Try fully qualifying your access. Posting an extract of your code would really be helpful though, I'm no good at clairvoyance :-)

Comment: Objective-C doesn't have namespaces.